# Qual a diferença entre Compile e Implementation no arquivo build.gradle do Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependências, android-gradle

Sempre que vou adicionar alguma biblioteca manualmente no arquivo **build.gradle (Module: app)** do *Android Studio 3*, eu utilizo o formato **implementation**, porque essa é a forma que o próprio Android Studio utiliza por padrão, mas sempre que pesquiso na internet qual biblioteca é necessária para um recurso especifico, encontro exemplos utilizando o formato **compile**.

Em todos os casos eu sempre substitui **compile** por **implementation** e nunca deu problema, mas estou curioso pra saber qual a diferença entre os dois formatos de adicionar bibliotecas ao projeto.

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    //...
}

dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    //...
}
```

Comment: Até onde eu sei, implementation passou a ser suportado na versão mais nova do gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no Stackoverflow em inglês, segue a tradução:

É uma das mudanças de ruptura que vem com gradle: 3.0 que o Google [anunciou no IO17](http://%C3%89%20uma%20das%20mudan%C3%A7as%20de%20ruptura%20que%20vem%20com%20gradle:%203.0%20que%20o%20Google%20anunciou%20no%20IO17%20gradle:%203.0%20%20A%20compileconfigura%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20est%C3%A1%20agora%20obsoleta%20e%20deve%20ser%20substitu%C3%ADda%20por%20implementationouapi%20%20Dos%20documentos%20do%20gradle%20:) gradle: 3.0

A `compile` configuração está [agora obsoleta](https://youtu.be/7ll-rkLCtyk?t=29m18s) e deve ser substituída por `implementation` ou `api`

Dos [documentos](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) do [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) :

> ```
> dependencies {
>     api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
>     implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' 
> }
> ```
>
> As dependências que aparecem nas configurações `api` serão expostas
>   transitivamente aos consumidores da biblioteca e, como tal, aparecerão
>   no classpath de compilação dos consumidores.
>
> As dependências encontradas na configuração `implementation`, por
>   outro lado, não serão expostas aos consumidores e, portanto, não serão
>   vazadas no classpath de compilação dos consumidores. Isso vem com
>   vários benefícios:
>
> Dependências não vazam no ranking classpath de consumidores mais,
>   então você nunca irá depender acidentalmente de uma dependência
>   transitiva compilação mais rápida graças ao tamanho reduzido do
>   classpath menos recompilações quando as dependências de implementação
>   mudam: os consumidores não precisariam ser recompilados publicação
>   mais limpa: quando usado em conjunto com o novo plugin maven-publish,
>   as bibliotecas Java produzem arquivos POM que distinguem exatamente o
>   que é necessário para compilar contra a biblioteca e o que é
>   necessário para usar a biblioteca no tempo de execução (em outras
>   palavras, não Misture o que é necessário para compilar a própria
>   biblioteca e o que é necessário para compilar contra a biblioteca).
>
> **A configuração de compilação ainda existe, mas não deve ser usada, pois não oferecerá as garantias oferecidas pela `api` e
>   `implementation`.**

Basta substituir:

- `compile` por `implementation`
- `testCompile` por `testImplementation`
- `debugCompile` por `debugImplementation`
- `androidTestCompile` por `androidTestImplementation`

**Esclarecendo:** O consumidor é o módulo que usa a biblioteca. No caso do Android, é o aplicativo Android.

**`implementation` x `api`:**  Se seu aplicativo depende da biblioteca x, que depende de y, z. Se você usar `implementation` apenas x api será exposto, mas se você usar `api` y, z também será exposto.

Fonte: [What's the difference between implementation and compile in gradle
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle/44493379#44493379)

Answer (score 7):

### A configuração `compile` está obsoleta

É uma das grandes mudanças vindas do gradle:3.0, que a google anunciou em 2017 na google I/O

A configuração `compile` está agora depreciada e você deve substituir por `implementation` ou `api`. Onde a configuração `api` deve ser usada para declarar dependências na qual serão exportadas pela biblioteca da API, enquanto que `implementation` deve ser usada para declarar dependências na qual são de uso interno do componente. Exemplo:

```
dependencies {
   api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
   implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
}
```

As dependências que aparecem nas configuração de `api` serão expostas transitivamente aos consumidores da biblioteca e, como tal, aparecerão no caminho de compilação dos consumidores.

As dependências encontradas na configuração de `implementation`, por outro lado, não serão expostas aos consumidores e, portanto, não serão vazadas no classpath de compilação dos consumidores. Isso permite uma **compilação mais rápida** graças ao tamanho reduzido do classpath.

Se você tiver um conhecimento de inglês, aqui esta a [documentação](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).

Substitua no seu código:

- compile por implementation
- testCompile por testImplementation
- debugCompile por debugImplementation
- androidTestCompile por androidTestImplementation

[Este artigo](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) fala um pouco dessa e de outras mudanças que ocorreram na nova versão. Além de mostrar como migrar de uma versão mais antiga do gradle para a mais atual.

> A configuração `Compile` ainda existe, mas não deve ser utilizada por não oferecer as garantias que as configurações `api` e `implementation` fornecem.